# db2 import from pipe delimited file not working

Tags: import, db2

```
import from "/tmp/ABC/DEF.txt" of del modified by coldel| messages "/tmp/ABC/msg.txt" insert into SCHEMA.TEMP_Table
```

contents of file

```
NA|ABC00111100000033360717182
NB|ABC00222000000000170717237
```

When I use this I am not able to get the NA and NB in the table - I am able to get the second part in the pipe delimited file to the seond column of my table but The first column is blank

the temp table has both vatchar columns - Can you pls help

Comment: please provide your create table statement and look into your messages-file for more responses. second: CR/LF maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the pipe symbol "|" is interpreted by your operating system, so your call is:

```
root@server> db2 import from "/tmp/ABC/DEF.txt" of del modified by coldel
```

I did a create table (guessing your statement) and executed your statement and all went nice, so the problem may be in your create table statement or in the CarrigeReturn/LineFeed of your input file

Comment: Yes there was a Ctrl M character and it worked after that Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The IMPORT utility will let you specify special delimiter characters by providing their hex ASCII codes, so specifying the pipe character as a delimiter would be `MODIFIED BY COLDEL0x7c`

You could also save the import command into a text file (with no escaping of any kind) and execute it from the CLP as `db2 -f yourimportfile.sql` or `db2 -tf yourimportfile.sql` for multi-line commands that are terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: Yes there was a Ctrl M character and it worked after that Thanks